# How to use RXJS to make a click event emit a value in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

1. I hope not to get dom directly.Not use `document.querySelector`、`ViewChild`...
2. I need to create an Observable and mount the internal variables `this.subscribe = subscribe` to the component instance. I think this is not good, very jumping.

```js
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subscriber, Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<button (click)="onClick()">button</button>',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  subscribe!: Subscriber<void>

  subscription!: Subscription

  count: number = 0

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = new Observable<void>((subscribe) => {
      this.subscribe = subscribe
    })
      .subscribe(() => {
        console.log('update', ++this.count)
      })
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription?.unsubscribe()
  }

  onClick() {
    this.subscribe.next()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you haven't discovered [`Subject`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects) yet because you have sort of reinvented it :-)

Basically `Subject` is an object that you can subscribe to as an Observable, but you can also push values through by calling its `.next()` method.

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  click$ = new Subject<void>()

  subscription!: Subscription

  count: number = 0

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = this.click$.subscribe(() => {
      console.log('update', ++this.count)
    })
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription?.unsubscribe()
  }

  onClick() {
    this.click$.next()
  }
}
```

---

You could define your `count` as an observable by using the [`scan`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/scan) operator like this:

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  subscription!: Subscription

  private click$ = new Subject<void>()

  count$: Observable<number> = this.click$.pipe(
    scan(previous => previous + 1, 0),
    tap(count => console.log('update', count))
  )

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = this.count$.subscribe()
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription?.unsubscribe()
  }

  onClick() {
    this.click$.next()
  }
}
```

---

In many cases you don't need to subscribe in your component, you can use the  [`async`](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe#description) pipe in your template instead.  This alleviates the need to keep track of `Subscription` and also doesn't require implementing `OnInit` and `OnDestroy`:

```js
export class AppComponent {

  private click$ = new Subject<void>()

  count$ = this.click$.pipe(
    scan(previous => previous + 1, 0),
    tap(count => console.log('update', count))
  );

  onClick() {
    this.click$.next()
  }
}
```

Then in your template, do something like:

```html
<p> {{ count$ | async }} </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you already have an observable, (click) is an event emitter which extends an RxJs subject. So (click)="onClick()" is telling your component to subscribe to the click event emitter of the button with your onClick function, what extra observable do you need?